# How to find the class index of a clicked element using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, django, tabs

I have a tab-based website where tabs are created dynamically by cloning the default tab view, however, without knowing the index number of each element there is no way to perform logic on each tab.

```
function search(){
    window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            event.preventDefault();
            alert(click)
            var input = document.getElementsByClassName("myTextInputID")[click].value;
            if (input.includes("https://www.amazon.co.uk/")) {
                document.getElementsByClassName("prodcont")[click].style.display = "block"
                document.getElementsByClassName("imgcont")[click].innerHTML = '<img class="image" src="https://www.needforseat.de/media/image/22/15/b3/MAXNOMIC-R-_LVL_Edition_Pro_YkaFLtIVOgbL1_320x463.jpg">';
                document.getElementsByClassName("h1")[click].innerHTML = prodName;
                document.getElementsByClassName("containFORM")[click].style.backgroundColor = "white"
                
            } else {
                URLerror.appendChild(urlerror);
                var cont = document.getElementsByClassName("containFORM")[click];
                cont.insertAdjacentElement("afterend", URLerror);
                setTimeout(function() {
                    URLerror.remove();
                }, 2000);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The only solution I've managed to come up with is by iterating through all the classes and givingibng them a `name` that matches their class number then whenever the tab button is clicked it returns its name. However this only works for the first 2 tabs and only goes up to an index number of one however when I add an alert for the value of `clicked` it shows the right value but the code runs on class index [1] which is very confusing.

```
    <div class="tabcontainer" id="tabcon" style="background-color: aquamarine">
        <ul id="navigation1">
            <li class="tabli" id="button1"><button class="tabs" id="default" onclick="openPage('0', this, 'red'); buttonOnclick(this.name);"></button></li>
            <ul id="navigation2">
                <li id="tabli">
                    <button onclick="newTab()" class="addbut" style="text-align: center">+</button>
                </li>   
            </ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

```
function buttonOnclick(clicked) {
    
    for (let x = 0; x < document.getElementsByClassName("tabs").length; x++){
        document.getElementsByClassName("tabs")[x].name=x
        click = clicked
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Could you set up a working example?

Answer (score 0):

> without knowing the index number of each element there is no way to perform logic on each tab

You'll be glad to know that's not true. Your event handler is called with a `KeyboardEvent` object which, like all `Event` objects, has a `target` property with a reference to the element the event was targeted at. From there you can find its container using [`closest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) with a CSS selector, and you can find any elements within that container using [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) (to find the first match for a CSS selector) or [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) (to find all matches).

I can't quite make out what you're doing in your code, but this will give you the `.tabcontainer` element that contains the element the event targeted:

```
const container = event.target.closest(".tabcontainer");
```

Here's an example:

```js
window.addEventListener("keyup", function(event) {
    // Find the container
    const container = event.target.closest(".tabcontainer");
    if (!container) {
        console.log("Couldn't find container for keyup");
        return;
    }
    
    // Find the counter element
    const counter = container.querySelector(".counter");
    
    // Increment it
    counter.textContent = +counter.textContent + 1;
});
```

```html
<div>Start by clicking here to focus the document, then press <kbd>Tab</kbd> to tab to the "tabs" below and press some keys&nbsp;&mdash; watch the counter for that "tab" increase.</div>
<div class="tabcontainer" style="background-color: aquamarine">
    <ul>
        <li class="tabli" autofocus tabindex="0">this can be tabbed to</li>
        <li>Keyups in this tab: <span class="counter">0</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tabcontainer" style="background-color: aquamarine">
    <ul>
        <li class="tabli" autofocus tabindex="0">this can be tabbed to</li>
        <li>Keyups in this tab: <span class="counter">0</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tabcontainer" style="background-color: aquamarine">
    <ul>
        <li class="tabli" autofocus tabindex="0">this can be tabbed to</li>
        <li>Keyups in this tab: <span class="counter">0</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tabcontainer" style="background-color: aquamarine">
    <ul>
        <li class="tabli" autofocus tabindex="0">this can be tabbed to</li>
        <li>Keyups in this tab: <span class="counter">0</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="tabcontainer" style="background-color: aquamarine">
    <ul>
        <li class="tabli" autofocus tabindex="0">this can be tabbed to</li>
        <li>Keyups in this tab: <span class="counter">0</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: *(Oops, bit a typo there. If you see `this.target` in the one-liner above, hit refresh. It should be `event.target`.)*